# How many distinct holomorphic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is there?

Tags: complex-analysis, cardinals, self-learning

Is this proof OK ?

Considering that the constant function $f(z) = c$ is analytic for all $c \in \mathbb{C}$, there is at least $\mathfrak{c}$ (the power of the continuum) holomorphic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Since a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$, there must be at most card$(\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{c}\cdot \mathfrak{c}$ functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Assuming the axiom of choice, $\mathfrak{c}$ is an $\aleph$ and we know that the $\aleph$ satisfy $\aleph_\zeta \cdot \aleph_\zeta = \aleph_\zeta$. So there is at most $\mathfrak{c}$ holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There are $2^\mathfrak c$ functions from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: you  have one function for each subset of $\mathbb C$ by identifying the set with is characteristic function.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann-Roch Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem

Comment: Would my argument be valid for entire functions ?

Comment: @M.G Where are you using that the functions are holomorphic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every entire function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is uniquely determined by its power series coefficients $\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, \}$.

Comment: So if I get it well, it means that there exist $\mathfrak{c}\cdot \aleph_0 = \mathfrak{c}$ such entire functions, right ?

Comment: @M.G You're looking at $\Bbb C^{\Bbb N}$.

Comment: I see... thanks.

Comment: Still, would you be so kind as to point out where my "proof" went wrong ?

Comment: The set of functions $A \rightarrow B$ has cardinality $|B|^{|A|}$.

Comment: The be more specific, is it true that $\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$ ?

Comment: @M.G: Yes.  Write $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and use the "laws of exponents".

Answer (score 5):

Hint: A continuous function is determined by its values on a dense set.

Comment: Ah, good to see you are active again!

Comment: How do we know there isn't overcounting?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Nice to see you again!

Comment: @Christopher: The hint is quite abstract, but you can use it to show that there are at most $\frak c$ functions; since the other inequality was already proved in the question, this finishes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that not every subset can be the range of an entire function, e.g., Liouville's theorem implies bounded sets must be singletons. That's why your argument doesn't work.